# php Замена ссылок на параграфы

Tags: php, парсер

Подскажите, как произвести замену в спаршеном `html` тексте тегов `<a>...</a>` на `<p>...</p>`; Использую [simplehtmldom](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/api/simple_html_dom_node/outertext/)

Есть вот такой код который убирает href с спаршеного контента

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($htmlContext, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$links = $xpath->query('//a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $link->removeAttribute('href');
}
```

Как его дополнить что б заменить ссылки на параграфы?

Пробовал через

```
$result = preg_replace('/<a [^>]*?href="(http:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\\.:\/]+?)">([\\s\\S]*?)<\/a>/',
    '<p>\\2</p> [\\1]', $dom);
```

но это не отрабатывает хотя $dom - и строка с html контентом ..

Так же пробовал через

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $link->removeAttribute('href');
    $link->outertext="<span>".$link->innertext."</span>";
}
```

не отрабатывает как надо.

Дополнено $link --- объект

```
object(DOMElement)#12390 (18) {
  ["tagName"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["schemaTypeInfo"]=>
  NULL
  ["nodeName"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["nodeValue"]=>
  string(8) "Shakhtar"
  ["nodeType"]=>
  int(1)
  ["parentNode"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["childNodes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["firstChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["lastChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["previousSibling"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["nextSibling"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["attributes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["ownerDocument"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["namespaceURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["localName"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["baseURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["textContent"]=>
  string(8) "Shakhtar"
}
```

Comment: Приведите небольшой фрагмент html до и после

Comment: А почему вы пишите про simplehtmldom, а используете DOMDocument ?

Comment: Регулярное выражение может быть [проще](https://regex101.com/r/2qp9hx/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = <<<HTML
<div>
    <a href="#active" class="active">Text Link</a>
    <a href="#active-2" class="active">Text Link 2</a>
    <a href="#active-3" class="active">Text Link 3</a>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$links = $xpath->query('//a');
$div = $xpath->query('//div'); //Находим элемент-родитель, в котором есть ссылки. Может быть хоть body

foreach ($links as $key => $link) { //Пробегаемся по объекту ссылок
    $newLink = $dom->createElement('p'); //Создаём новый элемент-параграф
    $newLink->textContent = $link->textContent; //Копируем в него необходимые атрибуты от тега a
    $div[0]->appendChild($newLink); //Добавляем в родительский элемент параграф
    $div[0]->removeChild($link); //Удаляем из родительского элемента ссылки
}

$newDom = $dom->saveHTML(); //Сохраняем документ в новый HTML

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newDom);
echo '</pre>';

/*
Результат такой получился
<pre>
string(217) "
<div>
    
    
    
<p>Text Link</p><p>Text Link 2</p><p>Text Link 3</p></div>
"
</pre>
*/
```

Comment: не совсем. Добавил что содержится в $link. Там объект.  А в $links кусок html

Comment: @BlackStar1991, изменил ответ. Вот такой вариант надумал. Может, то, что нужно вам

Comment: Пробел не стоит удалять, это убивает остальные элементы и их содержимое

Comment: И правда! Поправлю ответ

Answer (score 0):

Возможно должно быть так?

```
// $dom - DOM object
foreach ($links as $link) {
   if ($parent = $link->parent) {
       $parent->removeChild($link);
       $parent->appendChild($dom->createElement('p', $link->innertext));
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function removeChild() on null in  Не отрабатывает чего-то.  Там много ссылок в html

Comment: Странно, что в DOM у ссылок нет родителя. Добавил проверку на существование, но линки, не отдающие родителя, не отработают

Comment: ` Notice: Undefined property: DOMElement::$parent in ...`  не отрабатывает. Замена не происходит(

Comment: Отличное решение. Но cвойство называется __parentNode__, а вместо `$link->innertext` нужно `$link->textContent`.